# Creating a sequence object from SPELL data

Tags: r, traminer

I am trying to create a sequence object with `seqdef` using SPELL format. Here is an example of my data:

```
spell <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 
12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 
19), status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1), time1 = c(1, 1, 57, 1, 1, 91, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 104, 1, 1, 60, 109, 121, 1, 42, 47, 54, 64, 72, 78, 
85, 116, 1, 29, 39, 69, 74, 78, 88, 1, 16, 40, 68, 1, 30, 123, 
1, 39, 51, 1, 61), time2 = c(125, 57, 125, 125, 91, 125, 125, 
125, 125, 125, 104, 125, 125, 60, 109, 121, 125, 42, 47, 54, 
64, 72, 78, 85, 116, 125, 29, 39, 69, 74, 78, 88, 125, 16, 40, 
68, 125, 30, 123, 125, 39, 51, 125, 61, 125)), .Names = c("ID", 
"status", "time1", "time2"), row.names = c(NA, 45L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I try to define the sequence object, a strange error is thrown:

```
spell.seq <- seqdef(data=spell, informat="SPELL", id="ID", begin="time1", end="time2", 
                    status="status", limit=125,process=FALSE)

 [>] time axis: 1 -> 125
 [>] SPELL data converted into 17 STS sequences
 [>] 3 distinct states appear in the data: 
     1 = 1
     2 = 2
     3 = 3
 [>] state coding:
       [alphabet]  [label]  [long label] 
     1  1           1        1
     2  2           2        2
     3  3           3        3
 [>] 17 sequences in the data set
 [>] min/max sequence length: 125/125
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length
```

However, if I do the same indirectly via `seqformat`, preserving the same arguments, no error is thrown:

```
sts <- seqformat(data=spell,from="SPELL",to="STS",
                 id="ID",begin="time1",end="time2",status="status",
                 limit=125,process=FALSE)

seqs <- seqdef(sts,right="DEL")
```

Using TraMineR 1.8-5 with R 3.0.0 Windows 7 64-bit. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the detailled bug report (so yes, it is a bug). I have also noticed that the first call do not give the correct number of sequences. For now, please use seqformat separatly.

Comment: @MatthiasStuder By accident pasted the results from the main data, not the example. Edited. The error persists of course.

Comment: @MatthiasStuder I looked on the listed bug reports and didn't see this referenced, so to update you... this may not be an error as the documentation is rather specific (as quoted in the answer below).

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at the source of `seqdef()` for how the `row.names` are set shows they are set based on the value of the `id` argument.

Looking in `?seqdef` for `id` shows

> id
>   optional argument for setting the rownames of the sequence object. **If NULL (default), the rownames are taken from the input data.** If set to "auto", sequences are numbered from 1 to the number of sequences. A vector of rownames of length equal to the number of sequences may be specified as well.

From the example in the question you are passing `id="ID"` which does not meet these criteria. Changing this to `id=NULL` allows the command to complete as expected and a check for equality using `identical( spell.seq, seqs)` yields `true`.